# How do I turn off mail notifications for specified Facebook Pages when getting a message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have three pages:

```
www.facebook.com/pagea
www.facebook.com/pageb
www.facebook.com/pagec
```

Fans will sometimes send a message to the pages.

Currently I will get email notifications when someone send me a message but how can I turn off for some and keep some others?

For example, I want to get email update when I receive a message at `pagea` but not for `pageb` and `pagec`. How can I set that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your personal profile page, select Settings > Notifications, and then turn on/off from there. See below:

[image: Notifications]